# Android - pushnotification from JSON url

Tags: android, json, notifications, push

I'm using Volley to download certain JSON data. Now I want to implement notifications. My issue is related with that every user is using their own json urls with their own data. So what I want to achieve?

I want to have some kind thread running in background and for example checking data every 5 minutes, checking if values reached some certain condition and if yes then push notification to user. What is correct way to do that?

With regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to use Intent service. How to make it you can see in documentation.  You can send your events or raw json data to Intent service and to do something there, if you need sequentially processing you can use additional queue there.

for example

```
public class NotifyIntentService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { }
}
```

there you can see about queues (http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/executorservice-10-tips-and-tricks.html#!/2014/11/executorservice-10-tips-and-tricks.html)